# How to SPOP from a set, and SADD to another set using lua

Tags: redis

I have a SET that contains keys that I want to perform server side processing on.

I want to SPOP and item, and then also SADD to another set.

So I will have the following 2 sets:

```
1. Source 
2. Processing
```

I can't use SUNIONSTORE to POP from #1 and store in #2 as I need to keep all the keys that I have processed.

I want this process to be atomic, how can I do this with LUA?

Also, if I wanted to SPOP more than 1 key, can I still use LUA for this?

**update**

```
redis.replicate_commands()
local s = KEYS[1]
local p = KEYS[2]
local u = KEYS[3]
local ele = redis.call("SPOP", s)
if redis.call("SISMEMBER", ele, u) == 0 then
  redis.call("SADD", p, ele)
  redis.call("SADD", u, ele)
  return ele
else
  return "EXISTS"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Lua, but only with Redis v3.2 or above because `SPOP` is a non-deterministic command. The way to do this is by using the [command replication mode](https://redis.io/commands/eval#replicating-commands-instead-of-scripts) like so:

```
redis.replicate_commands()
local ele = redis.call('SPOP', KEYS[1])
redis.call('SADD', KEYS[2], ele)
```

The same logic can be applied for popping from multiple keys, for example:

```
redis.replicate_commands()
local elems = {}
local target = table.remove(KEYS, 1)
while #KEYS do
  local key = table.remove(KEYS, 1)
  elems[#elems+1] = redis.call('SPOP', key)
end
redis.call('SADD', target, unpack(elems))
```

Comment: how much overhead is there calling a lua script versus plan old redis commands?  is it significant?

Comment: You should test that yourself, but generally speaking the penalty is very low. Make sure you use `EVALSHA`.

Comment: See my updated Q, I'm getting the error ```(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_91aac8622d7da23bbbc2354cbbf547755d85f15f): @user_script:1: user_script:1: attempt to call field 'replicate_commands' (a nil value)```

Comment: running exactly what have in your first snippet, I get `attempt to call field 'replicate_commands' (a nil value)`.  I am running redis 3.2.8

Comment: I've verified that the above runs on 3.2 - are you sure that you're running 3.2.8? Is this a self-operated or a hosted Redis instance?

Comment: I am doing this locally, and I have 2 versions installed using homebrew and it was running the older version thanks!